# Non-static method Waavi\Translation\Repositories\Repository::find() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

This code in my controller

```
$language = LanguageRepository::find(1);
```

throws out the following error:

> Non-static method Waavi\Translation\Repositories\Repository::find() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Can somebody tell me why does it is giving me this error?

Comment: You have answer below, by @Joseph or simply `use ..path_to_that_class\LanguageRepository;` at the top of your controller

Comment: it doesn't matter I entered use Waavi\Translation\Repositories\LanguageRepository; but it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate your repository:

```
$language = (new LanguageRepository(new Language))->find(1);
```

Comment: Now it says "Argument 1 passed to Waavi\Translation\Repositories\LanguageRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Waavi\Translation\Models\Language, none given"

Comment: @OunknownO - Then you have to pass a new model into the constructor. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now it says Argument 2 passed to Waavi\Translation\Repositories\LanguageRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application, none given,